# Angular 8 mat video player time is not working?

Tags: html, angular, angular8

I want to achieve that pause video on particular time, also in mat video player mentioned - time    number (two-way bindable)   Get or set the timestamp of the video   0.

HTML template file:

```
<mat-video #video [src]="src" title="My Tutorial Title" [(time)]="ctime"  [autoplay]="true" [preload]="true" [download]="false" color="accent" spinner="spin">
</mat-video>
```

TypeScript code:

```
ctime = 30;
src="assets/bloodborne pathogens.mp4";
```